# How to test angular $cacheFactory?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, caching

I am using $resource in an angular service.
I want to use my own custom cache based upon $cacheFactory, rather than the built-in $http cache, so that I can manipulate the cache when responses arrive back from my REST service.

I am having great difficulty mocking out the $cacheFactory in my unit test, Could someone help me define the right mock and setup for my tests?

Here is the simplified version of the code I am trying to test. Notice that I am telling my angular app to use my custom cache `'DefaultCache'` instead of the default `$http` cache it would otherwise use, in `myApp.run()`. (I understand this to be the way to replace the default cache for all my $resource services).

### The Code

```
var myServices = angular.module('myServices', ['ngResource']);

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'myServices'
]);

myApp.run([
    '$http',
    '$cacheFactory',
    function ($http, $cacheFactory) {
        // Replace default $http cache with one we can control
        $http.defaults.cache = $cacheFactory('defaultCache');
    }]);

myServices.factory('MyService', [
    '$resource',
    '$cacheFactory',
    function($resource, $cacheFactory) {

        var cache = $cacheFactory.get('defaultCache');

        function doSomething(data) {
            var cached = cache.get('akey');
            return angular.fromJson(data);
        }

        return {
            things: $resource('/api/things/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
                query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: true,
                    cache: true,
                    transformResponse: function(data) {
                        return doSomething(data);
                    },
                },
            })
        }
    }]);
```

### The Test

and this is my test setup. (Notice: that the provided mockCacheFactory returns an object):

```
///<reference path="~/Scripts/jasminejs/jasmine.js"/>
///<reference path="../../Web/Scripts/angularjs/angular.js"/>
///<reference path="../../Web/Scripts/angularjs/angular-mocks.js"/>
///<reference path="../../Web/Scripts/angularjs/angular-resource.js"/>

describe("MyServiceSpec", function () {

    beforeEach(module('myServices'));

    describe('GivenThingsResource', function () {

        var $httpBackend, MyService, mockCacheFactory;

        beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
            mockCacheFactory = {
                get: function (cacheName) {
                    return {
                        get: function (key) { },
                        put: function (key, value) { },
                    };
                },
            };

            $provide.value('$cacheFactory', mockCacheFactory);
        }));

        beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, _MyService_) {
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

            MyService = _MyService_;

            spyOn(mockCacheFactory, 'get').andCallThrough();
        }));

        it("WhenQuery_ThenReturnsData", function () {
            $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/things').respond(JSON.stringify({ Things: [{ Id: '1' }, { Id: '2' }] }));
            var result = MyService.things.query();
            $httpBackend.flush();

            expect(result).toEqualData({ Things: [{ Id: '1' }, { Id: '2' }] });
        });

    });
});
```

### Test Results:

The problem I am seeing is: that when the test runs, I get these two errors:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$httpBackend.expectGET') in http://localhost:35050/Tests.js (line 76)
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$httpBackend.expectGET')
    at  TestSpec.js: line 76
    at   jasmine.js: line 1064
    at   jasmine.js: line 2096
    at   jasmine.js: line 2086TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a function (evaluating '$cacheFactory('$http')')
TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a function (evaluating '$cacheFactory('$http')')
    at   angular.js: line 7527
    at invoke (  angular.js: line 3966)
    at   angular.js: line 3808
    at getService (  angular.js: line 3930)
    at invoke (  angular.js: line 3957)
    at   angular.js: line 3808
    at getService (  angular.js: line 3930)
    at invoke (  angular.js: line 3957)
    at   angular.js: line 3808
    at getService (  angular.js: line 3930)
    at invoke (  angular.js: line 3957)
    at workFn (  angular-mocks.js: line 2161)
    at   jasmine.js: line 1064
    at   jasmine.js: line 2096
    at   jasmine.js: line 2086
undefined
```

So, I am thinking my mock is wrong, so I changed the provided `mockCacheFactory` to a function, so that the call to `$cacheFactory('$http')` should succeed:

```
mockCacheFactory = function () {
    return {
        get: function (cacheName) {
            return {
                get: function (key) { },
                put: function (key, value) { },
            };
        },
    };
};
```

But I now get these errors:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$cacheFactory.get('defaultCache')')
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$cacheFactory.get('defaultCache')')
    at  TestSpec.js: line 25
    at invoke (  angular.js: line 3966)
    at   angular.js: line 3808
    at getService (  angular.js: line 3930)
    at invoke (  angular.js: line 3957)
    at workFn (  angular-mocks.js: line 2161)
    at   jasmine.js: line 1064
    at   jasmine.js: line 2096
    at   jasmine.js: line 2086
undefinedTypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$httpBackend.expectGET') in http://localhost:40529/Tests.js (line 78)
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$httpBackend.expectGET')
    at  TestSpec.js: line 78
    at   jasmine.js: line 1064
    at   jasmine.js: line 2096
    at   jasmine.js: line 2086
```

### Help Please

I don't really understand what is needed here in my mock to satisfy the code that is using my mock. It seems to need to have some javascript duality which I don't know how to mimic in my definition of the mock.

Does anyone know how my mock should be constructed? Or what else I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any one coming later with same problem.

I found no way to build a mock that works for this code. I even took the implementation of $cacheFactory (from github), stripped out its implementation and tried using that as the mock, plugging it in the test. No luck there either.

I did however, come across a random post that hinted that perhaps I should create a cachingservice of my own (in my own service), that would create a cache using $cacheFactory. Then, I could just inject my cachingservice into my resource (as normal for services) instead of using $cacheFactory directly. Mocking that caching service should be straightforward.

I did that, and its fine now.

My new caching service:

```
myServices.factory('ServiceCachingService', [
    '$cacheFactory',
    function (
        $cacheFactory
        ) {
        return $cacheFactory('defaultCache');
    }]);
```

New app.run():

```
myApp.run([
    '$http',
    'ServiceCachingService',
    function ($http, ServiceCachingService) {
        // Replace default $http cache with one we can control
        $http.defaults.cache = ServiceCachingService;
    }]);
```

My new data service:

```
myServices.factory('MyService', [
    '$resource',
    'ServiceCachingService',
    function($resource, ServiceCachingService) {

        function doSomething(data) {
            var cached = ServiceCachingService.get('akey');
            return angular.fromJson(data);
        }

        return {
            things: $resource('/api/things/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
                query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: true,
                    cache: true,
                    transformResponse: function(data) {
                        return doSomething(data);
                    },
                },
            })
        }
    }]);
```

And then the new test mock:

```
mockCachingService = {
    get: function (key) {},
    put: function (key, value) { },
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Today I struggled with the same issue and found a different solution to make this work. (Angular 1.3.13)

Apperantly $cacheFactory has a get method so you can retrieve the instance for the cacheId.
This will enable you to spy on the correct cache instance.

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_$cacheFactory_) {
  mockCache = _$cacheFactory_.get('defaultCache');
}));
```

---

```
it('your test', function () {
  spyOn(mockCache, 'get').andCallThrough();
  ....
  expect(mockCache.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('akey'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will allow you to mock out the $cacheFactory in your unit tests. The $provide service will allow the service dependency injection to use your $cacheFactory instead of the default $cacheFactory.

```
var cache, $cacheFactory; //used in your its
beforeEach(function(){
    module(function ($provide) {
        $cacheFactory = function(){};
        $cacheFactory.get = function(){};

        cache = {
            removeAll: function (){}
            //add other methods here
        };
        spyOn(cache, 'removeAll');
        spyOn($cacheFactory, 'get').and.returnValue(cache);

        $provide.value('$cacheFactory', $cacheFactory);
    });
});

describe('yourFunction', function(){
    it('calls cache.remove()', function(){
        yourService.yourFunction();
        expect(cache.remove).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29426640/1270786